# Pythoncom interface cast

Tags: python, envdte, pythoncom

I would like to attach to a remote process with a running Visual Studio instance using **pythoncom** and COM objects provided by Microsoft Development Environment.
So far I am able to acquire from *DTE object* a *debugger* object implementing [Debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.debugger?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) interface. However, I need to access the [Transports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte80.debugger2.transports?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) property of the debugger. It is implemented by [Debugger2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte80.debugger2.transports?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) class. So somehow I need Debugger2 instance instead of Debugger. In VB or C++ this can be done by a simple cast ([DTE -> DTE2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68shb4dw.aspx)).
But how can this be done in Python?

**QueryInterface**

Approach ends with exception

```
IID_DTE2 = IID("{2EE1E9FA-0AFE-4348-A89F-ED9CB45C99CF}")

def get_vs_instances():
    rot = pythoncom.GetRunningObjectTable()
    running_objects = rot.EnumRunning()

    while True:
        moniker = running_objects.Next()

        if not moniker:
            break

        ctx = pythoncom.CreateBindCtx(0)
        name = moniker[0].GetDisplayName(ctx, None)

        if name.startswith("!VisualStudio.DTE."):
            obj = rot.GetObject(moniker[0])
            dte = win32com.client.Dispatch(
                obj.QueryInterface(pythoncom.IID_IDispatch))
            dte2 = dte._oleobj_.QueryInterface(IID_DTE2)
```

> TypeError: There is no interface object registered that supports this IID

**Invoke**

(I took DISPID 1101 of Transports property from Python Object Browser.)

```
transports = dte.Debugger._oleobj_.Invoke(1101, 0x400, pythoncom.DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, True)
```

> pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352573, 'Member not found.', None, None)

*CastTo* does not help either because of error *The interface does not
appear in the same library as the object.* [(similar problem)](http://grokbase.com/t/python/python-win32/09194pncxv/casting-to-interface-from-different-typelib)

Any suggestions?

Comment: You're trying to cast from `IDispatch` to `IDebugger2`. You don't have an `IDebugger` anywhere, so you haven't written the equivalent of a C++ cast from DTE->DTE2 anywhere. Those are only equivalent the class is dispatch-automation-compatible (carries its names around in string form so it can be used VB4-style). Which may be true in this case, but I have no idea whether it is; it should say in the docs.

Comment: IDebugger2 does not exist. There is Debugger2 interface inheriting from Debugger. So DTE.Debugger instance does implement Debugger2 interface. Maybe it can be problem with typelib?

Comment: `Debugger2` is a dispatch-only interface?

Comment: Going throught the VS SDK header file - `MIDL_INTERFACE("8B5E2BFD-4642-4efe-8AF4-0B2DA9AAA23C") Debugger2 : public Debugger` defined in dte80.h
And `MIDL_INTERFACE("338FB9A0-BAE5-11d2-8AD1-00C04F79E479") Debugger : public IDispatch` defined in dteinternal.h

Comment: Does anybody know how to make things like this happen? I also need to access Debugger2 interface from via pywin32.